# Sort by the product of 2nd and 3rd fields(Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I have a file which contains a list of products. Each line looks like this:product - pcs - price. I'd like to sort it by the pcs*price value.

Comment: Go ahead and give it a try, and then ask again if something isn't working right. This isn't a free coding service.

Comment: Show sample data of your file with expected output and your attempts

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `awk` and `sort` can do what you want.

```
awk '{p = $2*$3; print p,$1,$2,$3}' your-file | sort -n
```

This will create a temp. variable named `p` and will assign the product of column 2 and 3 to it.

Then it will print out this product followed by the 3 first columns.

After that the linux `sort` command will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using a spreadsheet like excel or libreoffice, once you import the file into the spreadsheet, sorting and multiplying columns is really easy.

Having said that: if you are comfortable with GNU Awk, a script like this could work:

**artcls.awk**

```
BEGIN   { # sort array numerically
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        FS=" - "
      }

      { p = $2 * $3
        if ( p in lines ) {
          lines[ p ] = lines[ p ] "\n" $0
        }
        else lines[ p ] = $0
      }
END { for( p in lines ) print lines[ p ], p }
```

You can use it like this: `awk -f artcls.awk your_file`.